# How to set state to api data in the store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, store

I am trying to set my state to the data I'm getting from my API with a GETTER in the store.

during the `mounted()` lifecyclehook trigger the GETTER `getProducts()` which looks like this:

```js
export const getters = {
  async getProducts() {
    axios.get('/api/products')
      .then(res => {
        var data = res.data
        commit('setProducts', data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}
```

In the GETTER I try to trigger a MUTATION called `setProducts()` which looks like this:

```js
export const mutations = {
  setProducts(state, data) {
    state.products = data
  }
}
```

But when I run this I get the error **ReferenceError: commit is not defined** in my console.
So obviously what goes wrong is triggering the MUTATION but after looking for 2 days straight on the internet I still couldn't find anything.

I also tried replacing `commit('setProducts', data)` with:
this.setProducts(data)
setProducts(data)

Which all ended with the error **"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setProducts')"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function `getProduct` is defined in a Vue component, you have to access the store like this :
`this.$store.commit('setProducts', data)`

If your function is not defined in a Vue component but in an external javascript file, you must first import your store

```js
import store from './fileWhereIsYourStore.js'

store.commit('setProducts', data)
```

If your `getters` export is literally the definition of your store's getters, you can use the solution of importing the store first, but you should know that it is clearly not a good practice to make commits in getters. There must be a better solution to your problem.

EDIT : To answer your comment, here's how you could do it:

```js
// Your store module 
export default {
  state: {
    products: []
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_PRODUCTS(state, data) {
      state.products = data
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async fetchProducts(store) {
      await axios.get('/api/products')
        .then(res => {
          var data = res.data
          store.commit('SET_PRODUCTS', data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can fetch products and populate your store in each of your components like this :

```html
// A random Vue Component
<template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 async mounted() {
   await this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts')

   // now you can access your products like this
   console.log(this.$store.state.products)
 }
}
</script>
```

I didn't tested this code but it should be ok.

Comment: I think I might have confused getters and actions (I'm terrible at backend). The result which I want to create is a function that I can trigger on desired components with `mounted()` so when it does it performs an API call that returns data which I want to store in the state. I wanna do it like this so that I don't have duplicate API calls allover my project. Is it possible to do this with actions instead of getters? Or am I thinking completely wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have summarized it well. The problem here is that you confuse getters and actions. Actions are exactly the solution to your problem. Let me edit my answer to explain how to do it.

Comment: Answer edited 

Comment: Not sure if you're following the answer, so I ping you here @MarnixElling

Comment: Also, `async fetchProducts(store) {` can be destructured into `async fetchProducts({ commit }) {` for a slicker syntax (commonly used) to save a few letters down the road.

Comment: I changed `async mounted() { await this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts') }` to `async mounted() { this.fetchProducts() }` imported MapActions and added `...mapActions("products", ["fetchProducts",]),` at the top of my methods for cleaner code

Comment: @MarnixElling also, usually HTTP calls are made during `created()` hook (will give you a few milliseconds for a cleaner rendering). And if you're using Nuxt, you could use `fetch()` or `asyncData()` hooks to have more benefits thanks to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Only actions do have `commit` in their context as you can [see here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions).
Getters don't have `commit`.

Otherwise, you could also use [`mapActions`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components) (aka `import { mapActions } from 'vuex'`), rather than `this.$store.dispatch` (just a matter of style, no real difference at the end).

Refactoring your code to have an action as Julien suggested is a good solution because this is how you should be using Vuex.

Getters are usually used to have some state having a specific structure, like sorted alphabetically or alike. For common state access, use the regular state or the `mapState` helper.

[image]